# I've copied a directory with `cp -as` and now I'm terrified to `rm -rf` the created directory as it might delete the original

Tags: symlink, rm, cp

I've copied a directory with `cp -as /media/user/dir symlinks` and now I'm terrified to `rm -rf symlinks` as it might delete files in `/media/user/dir`

What is the safe way to only delete the directory structure and the symbolic links in `symlinks` *without* touching anything in `/media/user/dir`?

As a test, I did this:

```
$ mkdir test
$ touch test/file
$ mkdir test/dir
$ touch test/dir/file2
$ cp -as test syms
$ rm -rf syms
```

This test didn't touch the original  `test` directory. Is this a complete test? Is it always like this?

I don't have the space to make a backup of `/media/user/dir`

Comment: GNU `cp` with `-l` creates hard links, not symbolic links if I'm not mistaken? I'm not by a conveniently accessible GNU system where I can test at the moment.

Comment: @they you are correct. i fixed the question to specify  `cp -as ..`  not  `cp -al`

Comment: i could move `/media/user/dir` to `/media/user/hidden-dir` so the symbolic links don't point to the original any more?

Comment: *"I don't have the space to make a backup"* If you don't have a backup of your data, you have a more important problem than your file system structure...

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a reason to use `-f` (force) here; just do `rm -r`. It's probably a good idea to get out of the habit of using `rm -f` unless it's actually necessary (and you've thought about it).

Comment: From my experience rm will not follow symbolic links but just delete them. Maybe try a local sample scenario and use rm --verbose to learn what's been done.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You may remove the directory containing the symbolic links without fear that this would also remove the original files.

[The POSIX specification for the `rm` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html) says (about what happens when encountering a symbolic link):

> The `rm` utility shall not traverse directories by following symbolic links into other parts of the hierarchy, but shall remove the links themselves.

And then, a bit later (in the Rationale section):

> The `rm` utility removes symbolic links themselves, not the files they refer to, as a consequence of the dependence on the `unlink()` functionality, per the DESCRIPTION. When removing hierarchies with `-r` or `-R`, the prohibition on following symbolic links has to be made explicit.

The GNU `rm` manual doesn't say anything about this, but we must assume that it does not break with POSIX in this regard.  The manual on other systems sometimes contains this promise explicitly.  Here's [from OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/rm) (FreeBSD and NetBSD has identical wordings):

> The `rm` utility removes symbolic links, not the files referenced by the
> links.

... and [from AIX](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=r-rm-command) (Solaris has a similar wording):

> If the file is a symbolic link, the link is removed, but the file or directory that the symbolic link refers to remains.

Note that the behavior of `rm` with regards to symbolic links may be tested easily locally:

```bsh
$ touch file
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 myself  wheel  0 Feb 26 09:32 file
$ ln -s file link
$ ls -l link
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myself  wheel  4 Feb 26 09:32 link -> file
$ rm link
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 myself  wheel  0 Feb 26 09:32 file
```

A similar exercise could be carried out for symbolic links in a directory.

Comment: So basically "cp -s" is the same thing as doing "ln -s"?

Comment: @Clockwork With GNU `cp`, the `-s` option will cause the utility to create symbolic links instead of copies of files. So, yes, in a sense. It creates symbolic links.

Comment: To be honest, *"When removing hierarchies with -r or -R, the prohibition on following symbolic links has to be made explicit."* sounds scary: What has been the default without -r now needs an explicit option with -r, or what? That there is no "--no-follow" option at all must mean I misunderstand that sentence, and the tests confirm that, but still.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, it's unclear _who_ needs to make it explicit, but I believe the standard primarily talks to the people implementing the standard, i.e. the developers writing the code for `rm` in this case. The standard is not really a manual, but a specification (the manual is what you get with `man rm`, which is written by that developer).

Comment: Beware though that if `link` is a symlink to a directory itself `rm -r link/` may *empty* (but not remove) the directory (remove its contents) or remove only the link itself depending on the `rm` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a way to gain confidence about Deletion Process:**

Create a test setup (eg ./Delete_test/) with Directories, Sym-links and regular files within it.
Then CD to that test setup.
Now run `strace rm -rf ./* 2> /tmp/strace.rm` and capture the output.

Check `/tmp/strace.rm` with `vim` or `grep` and look for strings like fstat and unlink; It should show System Calls to something like `fstatat` and `unlinkat`; You should also see `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW` & `AT_FDCWD`. This means **"Do not follow Sym-links"** and "Use CWD"; **This should let you know that, in the case of Sym-links, the original Directories and files will not be involved in the Deletion Process & will be safe.**

**Some References:**
https://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink
https://linux.die.net/man/2/unlinkat
https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat
https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstatat